# Use of double pointer in linux kernel Hash list implementation

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I am trying to understand Linux Kernel implementation of linked list and hash table. A link to the implementation is [here](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.34/include/linux/list.h). I understood the linked list implementation. But i am little confused of why double pointers is being used in hlist (**pprev). Link for hlist is [here](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.34/include/linux/list.h#L554). I understand that hlist is used in implementation of hash table since head of the list requires only one pointer and it saves space. Why cant it be done using single pointer (just *prev like the linked list)? Please help me.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The reason can be found in one of the comments:

```
 547/*
 548 * Double linked lists with a single pointer list head.
 549 * Mostly useful for hash tables where the two pointer list head is
 550 * too wasteful.
 551 * You lose the ability to access the tail in O(1).
 552 */
```

If you had *prev instead of **pprev, and because we are trying to save memory, we don't include *prev in the head, then our hlist implementation looks like this:

```
struct hlist_head {
  struct hlist_node *first = null;
};

struct hlist_node {
  struct hlist_node *next;
  struct hlist_node *prev;
};
```

Notice that the `prev` pointer cannot point to the head, or `head->first` (unlike `**pprev`). This complicates the hlist implementation, as you'll see when we implement `hlist_add_before()`:

```
void
hlist_init(struct hlist_head *head) {
  head->first = null;  
}

void
hlist_add_head(struct hlist_head *head, struct hlist_node *node) {
  struct hlist_node *next = head->first;

  head->first = node;
  node->next = next;
  node->prev = NULL;
  if (next) {
    next->prev = node;
  }
}
```

Notice that `prev` has nothing to point to, in the above imeplementation of `hlist_add_head()`. So, now when you implement `hlist_add_before()` it looks like this:

```
void
hlist_add_before(struct hlist_head *head,
                 struct hlist_node *node,
                 struct hlist_next *next) {
  hlist_node *prev = next->prev;

  node->next = next;
  node->prev = prev;
  next->prev = node;

  if (prev) {
    prev->next = node;
  } else {
    head->first = node;
  }
}
```

Notice that now we need to pass in `head` as well to `hlist_add_before()`, which requires an extra `push` instruction for pushing `head` on the stack. Besides, there's an extra conditional check in the implementation, which further slows down things.

Now, try implementing other hlist operations, with `*prev` instead of `**pprev`, and you'll find out that your implementation is going to be slower than what you saw in the linux kernel.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my doubt is why not have *prev and have a doubly linked list. Using this you can traverse both ways. You can add and delete nodes in O(1). The memory used is same for both cases. I am obviously missing something here. Could you please point out my mistake?

Comment: i can't find performance gain by using hlist. Can you explain?

Answer (score 1):

There are two type of lists: regular list_head type, and hash list(hlist). "list_head" type has only one struct, i.e. "struct list_head". But hlist has two struct,"struct hlist_head" and "struct hlist_node". So for hlist, when trying to point to previous element, the element can be either of type "hlist_head" or "hlist_node". We cannot use one common pointer type to point to both element types. (of course, we can use void* but it is not a good type of pointer and need type cast before actually using it) So the solution is to let the "prev" pointer point to a common struct type, which is "struct hlist_node *". This common type is shared by field "first" in hlist_head and also field "next" in hlist_node. Therefore "prev" pointer becomes "struct hlist_node **" that can point to both hlist_head.first and hlist_node.next.