# the use of double pointer (type **)ptr in __register_chrdev_region (linux kernel, 4.14.13, x86_64)

Tags: c, linux-kernel

In the linux kernel (4.14.13, x86_64), the function [__register_chrdev_region()][1] declared a double pointer variable `struct char_device_struct **cp;` However, throughout the function, the value of `cp` is never directly used, it is always used like: `*cp`. I don't get the point here, why not just define a pointer like: `struct char_device_struct *cp`, then use the variable like `cp`. To be more clear, for example, if the variable has been defined like: `struct char_device_struct *cp`, the following piece of code from the function:

```
for (cp = &chrdevs[i]; *cp; cp = &(*cp)->next)
    if ((*cp)->major > major ||
       ((*cp)->major == major &&
       (((*cp)->baseminor >= baseminor) ||
       ((*cp)->baseminor + (*cp)->minorct > baseminor))))
            break;
```

could have been written like:

```
for (cp = chrdevs[i]; cp; cp = (*cp)->next)
    if ((cp)->major > major ||
       ((cp)->major == major &&
       (((cp)->baseminor >= baseminor) ||
       ((cp)->baseminor + (cp)->minorct > baseminor))))
            break;
```

So I don't know why the pointer `cp` is defined as a double pointer: `struct char_device_struct **cp`, then it is always used by its 'dereferenced' form `*cp` ?
[1]: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.14.13/source/fs/char_dev.c#L100

Comment: It's a well known technique of working with linked lists. Basically it allows for fewer checks and exceptional cases "if the list is empty/if we're looking at the last element, do this special thing".

Comment: I think you are talking about something like hlist_node. There is a double pointer `struct hlist_node **pprev`, and the reason of using the double pointer is explained here(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058592/use-of-double-pointer-in-linux-kernel-hash-list-implementation). But as far as I understand, the `struct char_device_struct **cp` can be replaced by `struct char_device_struct *cp` in the cased posted here. I still don't see any reason of using double pointer here :(

Comment: Write code to insert into a sorted linked list. You will see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because several lines below there is an assignment to `*cp`:

```
cd->next = *cp;
*cp = cd;
```

Comment: If the `cp` is declared as `struct char_device_struct *cp`, these two lines can be written as: `cp->next = cp; cp = cd;`

Comment: Well, `cp = cd` changes value of `cp` and `*cp = cd` changes value of `chrdevs[i]`.